# C# Is it possible to have arrays be printed indented by a few lines when printed

Tags: c#, arrays

In a text based game I am making I have menus such as the inventory and player stats set out in a box that looks like this:

```
    | |====================================| |
    | |                                    | |
    | |                                    | |
    | |====================================| |
```

I was wondering if it was possible to have it so that an array, in this case the inventory could be printed within this box without overlapping it.

Essentially, what I want to do it indent the printing of the array so that it fits within this box without any issues.

```
    Console.WriteLine("| | Your inventory contains:                                      | |");
        for (Arraycount = 0; Arraycount < 20; Arraycount++)
        {
            int inventory_position = Arraycount + 1;
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", Inventory[Arraycount]);
        }
```

Comment: well there's no standard way to "print" an array, per se. How are you printing yours? How are you printing the box?

Comment: I am using a for loop, i'll edit my question to show you

Comment: So... is each array element small enough to fit within the space between left and right border?

Comment: Take a look at `string.PadRight` or formatting to make your values "fit".

Comment: Yes, they will be, the box is much wider as I have printed the right border using Console.SetCursorPosition X number of times. Although it isn't efficient, I know no other way to do so.

Comment: If you want all items to be indented by 3 spaces you can simply add the whitespace before you print "   {0}"

Answer (score 1):

You can use a format-string with a specified width and left-alignment:

```
var items1 = new string[]
{
    "Item 1",
    "Hello World",
    "Here comes trouble aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbbbbb cccccccccccccc dddddddd"
};
Console.WriteLine("| | {0,-60} | |", "Your inventory contains:");
for (int i = 0; i < items1.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("| | {0,-60} | |", items1[i]);
}
```

The `"{0,-60}"` placeholder tells to format the first argument (`0`) with a minimum width of `60` and left-aligned (the `-` before `60`).

Just in case you might be tired of counting the right amount of border characters: you can use `Console.WriteLine("| |{0}| |", new string('=', 62));` for the upper and lower border that aligns nicely with the width 60 (+2 spaces) contents.